# C++ building console server log + commands

Tags: c++, multithreading, console

Hello I want to build a console server in C++..
it must write output of other threads but also receives commands
how can I do? I'm sure my example it's wrong :/ because cin blocks all...

```
static string output = "";

//The function we want to make the thread run.
void task1(string msg){
    for (int i= 0; i < 10; i++)
        output += "task1 says: " + msg + "\n";
}

void task2(string msg){
    char c;
    cout << output << endl << "_> ";
    output = "";
    cin >> c;
    cout << endl;
}

int main(){
    // Constructs the new thread and runs it. Does not block execution.
    thread t1(task1, "Hello");
    thread t2(task2, "Hello");

    //Makes the main thread wait for the new thread to finish execution, therefore blocks its own execution.
    t1.join();
    t2.join();

    char c;
    cin >> c;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all you have a race condition, where both threads can modify the `output` variable at the same time.

For the other problem, you need to use lower-lever platform specific functionality to check if there is input ready to be read from the standard input, and you probably need to use lower-level non-blocking functions to read that input as well. On a POSIX system (like Linux or OSX) you can use e.g. [`fcntl`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fcntl.html) to make `STDIN_FILENO` (the standard input file descriptor) non-blocking and then [`select`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/select.html) to poll and [`read`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/read.html) to read.

Comment: well I have not understand fully (I'm on windows)... example?

Comment: @Raffa50 In short: You can't use `std::cin` if you don't want input to block. You should look at the [Windows console functionality](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682010%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).